# HasMany relation entry point unauthorized on Loopback

Tags: acl, loopback, ownership

New to Loopback, I tried to make a simple API with a user model and a todo model.

The user model, named **Todoer**,is based on the built-in User model. create a todoer, login, logout, etc. works like a charm.
The **Todo** model is based on **PersistedModel** with no special ACLs on it for the moment.

I made a **Belongs To** relation from **Todo** model to **Todoer** model to have an ownership.
I made also a **HasMany** relation from **Todoer** to **Todo** to be able to retrieve all the todos of a user through the endpoint **GET /Todoer/{id}/todos**

With a todoer logged in, with the good token and id, I can easily have responses from Todoer endpoints reserved for logged users, like `GET /Todoer/{id}` for example, so I'm sure the authentication mechanism is working well.

But each time I want to hit `GET /Todoer/{id}/todos`, I only obtain a error message telling I'm not authorized. I'm always sure I gave the good token and Todoer Id obtained at login.

Even if I make a big ACL telling OK to everything to all on the Todoer model, it happens the same.

What did I miss ? I can't figure it out...

Thank you for your help...

Comment: Can you share your ACLs or even whole `Todoer.json`, `Todo.json` files? It looks fine on a first sight. When accessing a related model, the active ACL is still the one for the model you are calling. Therefore allowing all on `Todoer` should open related `Todo`s completely.

Comment: Ok. Here is the todoer.json :`{`
` "name": "Todoer",`
`  "base": "User",`
`  "idInjection": true,`
`  "options": {`
`    "validateUpsert": true`
`  },`
`  "properties": {},`
`  "validations": [],`
`  "relations": {`
`    "todos": {`
`      "type": "hasMany",`
`      "model": "Todo",`
`      "foreignKey": "todoerId"`
`    }`
`  },`
`  "acls": [`
`    {`
`      "accessType": "*",`
`      "principalType": "ROLE",`
`      "principalId": "$everyone",`
`      "permission": "ALLOW"`
`    }`
`  ],`
`  "methods": {}`
`}`

Comment: And here is the todo.json :
{
  "name": "Todo",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "text": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "done": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "todoer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Todoer",
      "foreignKey": "todoerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}

Comment: In order to try to understand, you can see in the ACLs I've opened everything on todoer model. But when I hit GET todoer/Id/todos, I still obtain this : {
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Autorisation requise",
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    "stack": "Error: Autorisation requise\n    [...]
  }
}

Comment: You could've also edit your question to get a code formatting, but thank you! I've posted my answer. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account ACLs of a built-in [`User`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/d1719fd9a8c7abff2858aa223a4d53eef0ec1540/common/models/user.json)model. You are actually running into its general `DENY` ACL rule. It takes priority over your general `ALLOW` ACL rule ([docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Controlling-data-access.html) on *ACL rule precedence*).

You can write more specific ACL rule to get pass it ([docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Accessing-related-models.html) on *Accessing related models*).

```
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__get__todos"
}
```

Another option, which might be in this case more convenient and safe, is to use a dynamic `$owner` role on `Todo` itself ([docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html) on *Dynamic roles*).

```
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW"
}
```

If you want to understand what is happening regarding to ACLs in your application, it's very useful to set a `DEBUG` environment variable to `loopback:security:*` to enable quite extensive security logging.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works perfectly. I didn't understood that the deny ACL of the built-in user model has took precedence on my grant rule. I then restricted the access to the GET todoers/id/todos to authenticated users, and it goes now exactly how I wanted.

Have a nice day !

Comment: Great. If this answer solved your problem, can you please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it?